# C++ to/from MyLanguage Converter via LLVM/Clang

Tags: c++, programming-languages, clang, converters, llvm

I want to experiment with Programming Language Design.
The feature set that I imagined would be doable in C++, meaning you could rewrite anything from "MyLang" in C++.

I thought it would be great to have a two-way-converter, from MyLang to C++ and the other way around. This way I can avoid writing a Compiler/Optimizer/Linker/VirtualMachine/whatever and just use all the good stuff which is available for C++.

In my preliminary search I came across LLVM/Clang and thought that it would be a great ease of work to use its underlying parsing and AST generation to do what I want. But closer looks have shown me that it is a gigantic beast of a project where getting started is not an easy thing to do. My current point of entry in clang is the clang-modernizer, since it looks nice, small enough and pluggable, but I imagine it would break as soon as I break anywhere with C++ syntax.
I want to stay on a higher level than LLVM IR, since MyLang would be very similar to C++ on a high level.

An example of conversion would be something that takes a `my.cpp` and a `my.hpp` file and combines it into a `my.lang` file, at this time it may be beeing 100% valid C++ in the output file. Later the `my.lang` file shall be reconverted, splitting the definitions and inline methods into the `my.hpp` file and the non-inline methods into `my.cpp` again. Later on I plan to add more deviations from C++ syntax, but this might be a good start.

The Questions:

1. Do You know of a Project/Framework/Toolkit that does exacly supply a two way converter, which is Open Source or maybe completely configurable to be allow what I want?
2. Do You think LLVM/Clang is the best option for creating a MyLanguage to C++ converter? Do You have good Alternatives?
3. Any (web-)literature that helps getting my foot in the right spot in the door for a Framework/Clang/YourAlternative?

The *Not*-Questions:

- I know what an AST is.
- I know C++ is a beast itself, I'm not really aiming at 100% C++ code compatibility right now.
- This is just research, I don't want to get anything *done* with it. ;-)

Thank you for your time!
Please be gentle, this is my first Question here.

Comment: ...You want something that can magically take any language (even one that isn't defined) and convert it to C++? I mean, if such a tool existed I think it'd cost millions of dollars. Every time I've tried to use a converter (C to Matlab, Matlab to C, C++ to C#, C to Verilog) they've been buggy as hell, and each of there were paid software from a different developer who was intimately familiar with the task...there is no "rosetta stone" for code, really.

Answer (score 1):

**Do You know of a Project/Framework/Toolkit that does exacly supply a two way converter, which is Open Source or maybe completely configurable to be allow what I want?**

I believe LLVM can do just what you want. However, I can't guarantee the resulting translation would be human readable.

I would create a front-end that compiles to LLVM IR. The IR can be easily converted to C++ with the the llvm static compiler, by targeting the C++ backend (**llc -march=C++**).

If you just want your new language to execute, there is no reason to convert it to C++ and then recompile it. You can JIT/Interpret utilizing the LLVM framework.

If you want any LLVM IR to be able to convert to your language, you can create a compiler target, that handles the generation.

**Do You think LLVM/Clang is the best option for creating a MyLanguage to C++ converter? Do You have good Alternatives?**

I believe the LLVM framework is the way to go. If all you want to do is focus on the compiler front-end, you can do just that. You will get all the back-end optimizations and all the targets included in the framework. This is nice to scope your focus.

In terms of developing the front-end for your language, you can take advantage of the [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) parser generator. This will help you develop to an AST. In addition, perform any optimizations and validations that you can do to an AST. After you have your AST you can create a visitor that navigates the AST to generate LLVM IR. There already exists a grammar file for C++ to start with [here](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1295920686207/antlr3.2_cpp_parser4.1.0.zip).

**Any (web-)literature that helps getting my foot in the right spot in the door for a Framework/Clang/YourAlternative?**

Compilers are awesome and extremely complex. I suggest you at least have the [purple dragon book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811). To get going on LLVM I would go through their [tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/). You go through the development of a language, from the front-end all the way to JITing.